# Messages dissapear too quickly from echo area

Tags: echo-area

When using flymake or similar, syntax highlighting messages will appear in the echo area when you move the cursor to the position of the error.

My problem is that it dissapears too quickly. After about half a second, the echo area clears for some reason unknown to me. Is there any way to configure the echo area such that messages do not get cleared?

Comment: One alternative solution is to check your `*Messages*` buffer. Flycheck errors get put there. This is also useful for very long messages.

Comment: What @lefenzy said. For ephemeral messages in the echo area, you either need to follow the call to `message` with `sleep-for` or (in some cases) `sit-for`, or you need to give up on seeing them in the echo area and just check buffer `*Messages*`, where they are logged. Messages shown during minibuffer input, via `minibuffer-message` are, however, another story - they are not logged in `*Messages*`.